# How can I tell a legitimate Shantae copy from a fake?

Tags: version-differences, shantae

I recently stumbled across the game Shantae for the Gameboy Color. Looking around for that game, I found several offers on eBay for over $500, and then... several modules for around $7-10 from China.

That seems like a large discrepancy. I mean, these modules must be fake or "unofficial", right? Is there another way to tell whether the cartridge is fake or real?

Comment: Hi @LStrike, I have edited your question to (hopefully) be more suitable to us and get it reopened. Any chance you could add pictures from the cheap vs expensive listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yours is real, then it is rare and worth the money. It was released for the GBC when the GBA had already been released.
That's probably why they didn't make very many, and thus why it's rare.

The Chinese listings you are referencing are definitely fakes.
The original cartridge is see-through, not red.

Whenever there's a Chinese seller with a stock photo selling multiple copies of a game, it's most likely selling fake copies. Especially if they're selling games that are supposed to be rare.

A lot of the time people are aware of this though, and just buy them because they like to have physical copies without dishing out exorbitant amounts of cash.

Comment: Let's also not forget that any Chinese GB game has to be fake. China only recently lifted its ban on video game consoles, so any console or game prior to the current generation (PS4/XBO/NSW) sold in China has to be either an import, or a fake.